# How to create IPA and PDK for ionic app

Tags: javascript, terminal, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm a complete noob and have no idea how to use the terminal. I followed all the instructions on the ionicframework app to create the app and having been working on it for a few weeks. But now I don't understand how to create the build out files. When I try to follow the instructions on the website and input:

```
$ionic platform add ios
```

the error I get in the terminal is:

```
-bash: platform: command not found
```

I don't know even know where to begin :(

Also the app folder I created is on the Desktop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have all the components needed to make this:

Install NodeJS from https://nodejs.org/en/

Install npm with `sudo npm install npm -g`

Install Cordova and Ionic with `npm install -g cordova ionic`

For iOS, you will need Xcode in last version (Download from App Store)

For Android, you will need the SDK [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/index.html)

Go to your project and type: 
`ionic platform add ios` 
`ionic platform add android`

For Android, you can make the apk with this tutorial: [Android Tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html)

For iOS, you will need the Xcode to do all, only type this before `ionic prepare ios`

Comment: I remember installing npm and cordova, would it mess up if i used those commands again? Also, when you say go to your project, you mean "cd Desktop/myApp" right?

Comment: I followed your instructions just for ios
and after i typed the : ionic platform add ios...i got this error:   Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
/bin/sh: cordova: command not found

Comment: If you're getting those sort of errors it sounds like you haven't ran `sudo npm install -g cordova ionic`

Comment: @GONeale there was some error installing cordova...looked it up and apparently you always have to use "sudo" with "npm"...now i just have download Xcode and Andriod SDK...i'll check back if I need more help..THANKS A BUNCH  :)